# Python threading, measuring progress percentage

Tags: python, multithreading

This is a sort of "best practices" question. I'm doing my first multi-threaded code and I'm wondering if I am measuring progress properly. Here's my code which does 16 file-copy threads at once, and I'm trying to create a progress bar. This code works but I want to know if this is the "right" way of doing it (for example what if multiple threads are writing to "copyCount" at once?):

```
import Queue, threading, os
import shutil

fileQueue = Queue.Queue()
destPath = 'destination/folder/here'

class ThreadedCopy:
    totalFiles = 0
    copyCount = 0

    def __init__(self):
        with open("filelist.txt", "r") as txt:
            fileList = txt.read().splitlines()

        if not os.path.exists(destPath):
            os.mkdir(destPath)

        self.totalFiles = len(fileList)

        print str(self.totalFiles) + " files to copy."
        self.threadWorkerCopy(fileList)

    def CopyWorker(self):
        while True:
            fileName = fileQueue.get()
            shutil.copy(fileName, destPath)
            fileQueue.task_done()
            self.copyCount += 1
            percent = (self.copyCount*100)/self.totalFiles
            print str(percent) + " percent copied."

    def threadWorkerCopy(self, fileNameList):
        for i in range(16):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.CopyWorker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        for fileName in fileNameList:
            fileQueue.put(fileName)
        fileQueue.join()

ThreadedCopy()
```

Comment: When _writing_ to `copyCount` you should use a lock to ensure thread safety, i.e. `with lock: copyCount += 1`. This removes any chance of miscounting. You may also choose to pass `CopyWorked` a list of files via an argument rather than a global variable. You might also choose to make `CopyWorker` shorter and do the progress calculations in a function in the main thread.

Comment: Hey 101, thanks! I'll look deeper into the documentation on locking, sounds like what I need to know. How would you go about putting the progress calc in the main thread? I don't immediately have an idea for how I would do that.

Comment: You could simply do something like `while copyCount < totalFiles: print percent; sleep(0.1)`.

Comment: I get the idea behind that but sorry I'm not getting it to work. Could you provide a code sample instead of just a comment? Then I can actually accept your answer :)

Comment: So I found a great site explaining locks! Pretty simple really, I updated my code and put the answer below. If you want to provide your own answer with the percentage fixed I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else interested yes I was definitely doing this wrong. I found this fantastic article which explains in pretty simple terms how to go about wrangling multiple threads using locks: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

And for an updated code sample:

```
import Queue, threading, os
import shutil

fileQueue = Queue.Queue()
destPath = 'destination/folder/here'

class ThreadedCopy:
    totalFiles = 0
    copyCount = 0
    lock = threading.Lock()

    def __init__(self):
        with open("filelist.txt", "r") as txt:
            fileList = txt.read().splitlines()

        if not os.path.exists(destPath):
            os.mkdir(destPath)

        self.totalFiles = len(fileList)

        print str(self.totalFiles) + " files to copy."
        self.threadWorkerCopy(fileList)

    def CopyWorker(self):
        while True:
            fileName = fileQueue.get()
            shutil.copy(fileName, destPath)
            fileQueue.task_done()
            with self.lock:
                self.copyCount += 1
                percent = (self.copyCount*100)/self.totalFiles
                print str(percent) + " percent copied."

    def threadWorkerCopy(self, fileNameList):
        for i in range(16):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.CopyWorker)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
        for fileName in fileNameList:
            fileQueue.put(fileName)
        fileQueue.join()

ThreadedCopy()
```